# Mongo is logging slow query log but profiling is zero

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDb-CE 4.4

I have a 2.4 GB mongod.log file.

I executed

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0);
```

I obtained

```
{ 
    "was" : 0.0, 
    "slowms" : 100.0, 
    "sampleRate" : 1.0, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

But still it is logging slow query... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting profiling level to zero turns off recording data to the collection `system.profile`, but will continue to log to the log file any operations slower than `slowms`.  You cannot stop logging slow operations, but you can set the slowms to a high value - `db.setProfilingLevel(0, 5000000)` which may have the same effect.  In this example it will log if it takes more than 5,000,000 ms (i.e.,  5,000 seconds).